# Windows Explorer forgets vertical position after navigating back

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, navigation

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit and I'm having some weird behavior.
In Windows Explorer, I'm viewing a directory with lots of sub-directories in "Details" view. I'm scrolled down a bit (see 1st screenshot).

[image: Before]

I enter a sub-directory (in this case, KDiff3) via double-click, then navigate back via the back button. Now, Windows Explorer has forgotten its original vertical scroll position. It's still highlighting the sub-directory I just came from, but now it's scrolled so that that sub-directory is all the way down (see 2nd screenshot).

[image: After]

I've never experienced this behavior before and it's a bit of a pain. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you think it was ever different? This is how it worked in Windows XP (the earliest version I could test easily) and this is how it still works. I'd like to claim that this is just the first time that you've acutely *noticed* it. The vertical scroll position is simply a state that is not stored in the history, but derived by scrolling down from the top of the view to the item that was selected. Arguably, your expectation may be biased by how web browsers typically store the scroll position in the history state nowadays.

While not a direct solution to your problem I'd like to suggest something that I like to do, sorting by date instead of name. This at least makes it more likely that relevant (recently modified) files and folders are at the top.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I just checked on another PC, and it behaves identically. I can't believe I never noticed this behavior before, though...